# Linq finding elements and foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, linq

My code is working however i am trying to find a more efficient way to accomplish this. Like a linq solution without the foreach loop something that would be better. I dont have any performance issues..

```
  List<Table> tables = getTables();
  foreach (TableCategories category in categories)
  {
   category.Tables=tables.FindAll(tbl => tbl.CategoryId == category.Id);
  }
```

For database i use pure ADO.NET not linq as i am using postgres.

Comment: "pure ADO.NET not linq" Huh? What does ADO.NET have to do with LINQ that makes you have to use one but not the other?

Comment: i mean i dont use linq to sql, in case someone says i should do something at database.

Comment: I would not recommend getting rid of the foreach here.  It would, effectively, be purposefully creating side effects inside of your query if you did...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
var tablesByCategory = getTables().ToLookup(t => t.CategoryId);
foreach(var category in categories)
{
    category.Tables = tablesByCategory[category.Id];
}
```

This is more efficient (assuming you have a lot of tables) because you build a lookup at the beginning in O(n) time, and then each lookup in the for loop is O(1) time, so you end up with O(m + n) instead of O(m*n) complexity.

Comment: thats what i wanted! thank you :) i will accept it when system allows me. i want to do the reverse also. for each table to associate it with a category. when fetching tables.

Comment: @Parhs: It should work fine in the other direction, too. Just use `.ToDictionary` instead of `.ToLookup` since you'll only have one category per table.